# Symfony Form + File Collection + oTm-mTo = saved files always deleted on owner update

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have an entity `Item` and and entity `File`

When I save my `item` form with `files` everything is ok but later, when I try to add a new `File` to my `Item` then all the related files get deleted from my table and I only get the newly added items.

The deletion is happening at `$form->handleRequest($request);` I tried dumping data before and after and can confirm 100% the deletion is happening there.

My `$itemEntity` is then pre-filled with the existing files but disappear after the `handleRequest` in `$form`

I am also using `add` method instead of `set` and have an `arrayCollection` in my entity

I looked into the profiler and can see a doctrine SQL request for deletion happening

This seems like a really weird behaviour to me; I was not deleting the item and I don't even have `orphanRemoval` or `cascade{delete}`.

In the end I had to manually recreate records of the old files in the database but that seems inappropriate and I am sure I am missing something.

the million dollar question ?

CONTROLLER

```
  $itemEntity = $em->getRepository(Item::class)->findOneBy([
       'uid' => $uid,
  ]);

  // create form
  $form = $this->createForm(NewItemType::class, $itemEntity);

  // if I dump Item Entity here I can see my old files
  $form->handleRequest($request);
  // if I dump Item Entity here they are gone and replaced by the new   ones

  // .... later but never reached
  $item->addFile($fileInstance);
```

ITEM ENTITY:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\File", mappedBy="item", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $file;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->file = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

FILE ENTITY:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $path;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Item", inversedBy="file")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $item;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $uid;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $type;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $position;

/**
 * @var boolean
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
private $main;

/**
 * @var UploadedFile|null
 */
protected $file;


public function getFile(): ?UploadedFile
{
    return $this->file;
}


public function setFile(UploadedFile $file): void
{
    $this->file = $file;
}

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getPath(): ?string
{
    return $this->path;
}

public function setPath(string $path): self
{
    $this->path = $path;

    return $this;
}

public function getUid(): ?string
{
    return $this->uid;
}

public function setUid(string $uid): self
{
    $this->uid = $uid;

    return $this;
}

public function getItem(): ?Item
{
    return $this->item;
}

public function setBike(?Item $item): self
{
    $this->item = $item;

    return $this;
}

public function getType(): ?int
{
    return $this->type;
}

public function setType(int $type): self
{
    $this->type = $type;

    return $this;
}

public function getDescription(): ?string
{
    return $this->description;
}

public function setDescription(?string $description): self
{
    $this->description = $description;

    return $this;
}

public function getPosition(): ?int
{
    return $this->position;
}

public function setPosition(?int $position): self
{
    $this->position = $position;

    return $this;
}

public function getMain(): ?bool
{
    return $this->main;
}

public function setMain(?bool $main): self
{
    $this->main = $main;

    return $this;
}
```

FORM COLLECTION TYPE

```
->add('item', CollectionType::class, array(
     'label' => false,
     'entry_type' => ItemFileType::class,
     'error_bubbling' => false,
     'entry_options' => [ 'required' => false, 'error_bubbling' => true ],
     'allow_add' => true,
     'allow_delete' => true
 ))
```

ITEM FILE TYPE

```
->add('file', FileType::class, [
     'label' => false,
     'required' => false
   ])

->add('description')

->add('main', CheckboxType::class,[
        'label'    => 'Make this one the main picture',
        'required' => false,
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common situation when it comes to `ArrayCollection`. First of all, you have `$file` variable in `Item` entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\File", mappedBy="item", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $file;
```

In fact, better call this variable `$files`, as long as it possible to attach a couple or more files to a single item.

And you should also have the following line in your code

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->files = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

The problem here is that when you call `handleRequest` it completely rewrite your 
`$files` property. As I think, this happens because you have just `set` method in your `Item` entity, while you should not have set method, but `add` and `remove`

```
public function addFile(File $file)
{
    if (!$this->files->contains($file)) {
        $file->setItem($this);
        $this->files->add($file);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeFile(File $file)
{
    $this->files->removeElement($file);

    return $this;
}
```

The point is not to completely rewrite `ArrayCollection`, but extend it. If you remove some item from a collection Doctrine will remove it from the database.

FYI This also may happen because `$files` collection was not pre-filled with an existing collection before submitting form

Comment: Hi Lunin, thank you for your answer; I am sorry I was not precise enough; I have indeed an `add` method that I am using. (I updated the question). So I am investigating your second suggestion that $file collection is not pre-filled. I am not sure how I should do that ? because if I dump before `handleRequest` I can see the collection in the object so it is pre-filled ?

Comment: well, then here is what happening in fact, you submit a form with only one file, `handleRequest` method assume that newly submitted collection is the most important, therefore it remove all previous files and add only new one. So you have few options here 1) submit old files along with new one (is not a case in this particular situation, but may work in some other case) 2) update request collection before submitting - add all existing files to it 3) set `allow_delete` option to false https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#allow-delete

Comment: So to clarify it one more time - `ArrayCollection` in newly submitted form contains only one new file, existing `Item` entity has a collection with all previous files, that is why they present before `handleRequest`. During `handleRequest` new and existing collections are compared and as long as new collection does not has all previous files those are considered as removed.

Comment: Thank you so much for this awesome explanation. I tested quickly with solution 3 and it seems to work however solution 2 seems the best for me but I could not find a way to implement it yet